# Notation for acid-base reactions of differing strengths - equilibrium?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium

I'm having trouble finding anything meaningful in textbooks or searches. My question is what is the correct notation for writing acid-base reactions when their strengths are varying? I know that theoretically all reactions are reversible but when is it appropriate to use equilibrium arrows for certain acid-base reactions?

e.g. would a weak acid - strong base reaction be regarded reversible?

for example would $\ce{NaOH + CH3COOH $\leftrightharpoons$ NaCH3COO + H2O}$ be suitable (disregarding the lack of states and my ineptitude in writing MathJax)

or would $\ce{NaOH + CH3COOH -> NaCH3COO + H2O}$ be more suitable?

Do we just simplify it into only considering the forward reaction for the sake of stoichiometric calculation?

Comment: Consider rather $\ce{CH3COOH(aq) + H2O(aq) <=> CH3COO-(aq) + H3O+(aq)}$ and $\ce{CH3COOH(aq) + OH-(aq) <=> CH3COO-(aq) + H2O(aq)}$

Comment: I understand this, so when the task is to write an equation for the above neutralisation would an equilibrium be more suitable, with sodium ions as spectators? Because most likely the equation is meant to be used for titration calculations, so it isn't appropriate to have the net ionic equation here, and having sodium spectators on either side seems somewhat clumsy. I suppose I should just be using the first equation: $\ce{NaOH + CH3COOH ⇋ NaCH3COO + H2O}$

Comment: I have thought it through again @Poutnik and the following approach seems more appropriate:

$\ce{NaOH(aq) + CH3COOH(aq) -> NaCH3COO(aq) + H2O(l)}$

$\ce{CH3COO-(aq) + H2O(l) \leftrightharpoons CH3COOH(aq) + OH-(aq)}$

as the first equation cannot be equilibrium as $\ce{NaOH}$ will not form again in any measurable quantity

Comment: In fact, NaOH(aq) is just a shortcut for independent Na+(aq) + OH-(aq). The same for sodium acetate. But if one insists on molecular reaction notation, one must accept the equilibrium for molecular notations of the acid and the salt.

Comment: I'm aware - I was just a little conflicted as to whether the whole reaction should be shown in equilibrium because that seems to insinuate that $\ce{NaOH}$ may be formed, which would neglect Sodium Hydroxide being a strong base. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In that formal reaction, in reality no NaOH is either consumed either created, as it is OH- that is both consumed and created by the opposite ongoing reactions at the equilibrium. So if NaOH can be formally consumed, it can be formally created as well. One can use both uni-/bi-directional notations, depending on the context and aspect to be point out.

Comment: Interesting - so in the context of titration (where one compound is gradually added) would the unidirectional notation be more correct for the neutralisation, and then bi-directional acetate-water reaction to explain an alkaline equivalence point? (As for neutralisation it doesn't make much sense to use bidirectional)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136889/discussion-between-poutnik-and-tgsweat).